# How can I set Mutt’s Fcc field from the command line?

Tags: mutt

I would like to send certain messages in [Mutt](http://www.mutt.org) with an empty Fcc field (so that no local copy of the sent message will be stored).

According to the [Mutt man page](http://www.mutt.org/doc/mutt.1.txt) there is no command line switch for that. Is there any way I can achieve it regardless?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a configuration that stops Mutt from storing sent mail, to make it do so permanently you can add the following to your .muttrc file:

```
unset record
```

or if you want to do it only once you can at the command prompt call mutt like this:

```
mutt -e "unset record"
```

Comment: Appears to be the correct option, but for some reason the Fcc still is filled when using this. I tried setting via **.muttrc**, via **-e** and via **:set copy=no** directly in mutt.

Comment: Just found out that it does work when using "unset record" instead. If you want to update your question, I'll gladly accept it. Thank you!

Comment: @user569825 thanks for that, I changed my answer in regards to that.